Server restarts when I run the mdadm --create command
I am not an educated computer guy, so please be gentle with me :)
I have a server I use to run plex with sonarr and radarr. I am trying to create a raid array on it. I have 10x 12TB drives and I want to use RAID 5
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and I connect from a laptop using ssh
Hardware specs are as follows
MB - Super Micro X11SCH-LN4F
CPU - Intel Xeon E-2224 Coffee Lake 3.4 GHz
Memory - Micron 16GB 288-Pin VLP ECC Unbuffered DDR4 2666
So first I use this command
sudo umount /dev/sdb?; sudo wipefs --all --force /dev/sdb?; sudo wipefs --all --force /dev/sdb

For drives b-k
Then I
sudo sgdisk -n 1:0:0 /dev/sdb 

For Drives b-k
and then I
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=10 /dev/sd[b-k]1

When I run the create command, it works initially but within a minute or two, as its building the array, the computer randomly restarts. The only errors I can see in the logs are ones like these ones ...
EDAC MC0: 1 CE ie31200 CE on unknown memory (csrow:2 channel:1 page:0x0 offset:0x0 grain:1 syndrome:0xf8)

EDAC MC0: 1 CE ie31200 CE on unknown memory (csrow:2 channel:1 page:0x0 offset:0x0 grain:1 syndrome:0x45)

Otherwise to me it looks like it just restarts for no reason. When the computer restarts the array is there, but instead of md0 it's md127, its status is clean, degraded and I can't get it to do anything from there.
Here's the system log right before the crash






IME using RAID5 across that many disks is a disaster waiting to happen; consider RAID6 at the very least. And ensure you have somewhere to take regular backups

What does the picture say? Please paste text as text

Why have you tagged with [tag:memory]? If that's what you suspect is the issue have you tested it?

I suspect its a memory issue based on my limited knowledge and what I see in the logs. However, I tested the memory recently and it all came back good. I could definitely use RAID 6, I will try to build a RAID 6 array tonight and see what happens

If you think it's a memory issue then there's absolutely no point whatsoever trying to build a RAID array. At best it'll fail visibly like it is now. At worst it'll fail invisibly and you won't notice until you find your data is corrupt. Address the memory issue first. Take a look at unix.stackexchange.com/q/83257/100397 for suggestions - including the possibility that the report itself is a bug


Jul 11 17:56:15 media kernel: [  120.071518] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 357 at drivers/edac/edac_mc.c:999 edac_raw_mc_handle_error+0x216/0x250



Jul 11 17:56:15 media kernel: [  120.071523] Modules linked in: cmac nls_utf8 cifs cifs_arc4 cifs_md4 fscache netfs ipmi_ssif intel_rapl_msr binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_common intel_tcc_cooling x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm rapl intel_cstate wmi_bmof 8250_dw joydev input_leds mei_me mei intel_pch_thermal ie31200_edac acpi_ipmi ipmi_si ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler mac_Jul 11 17:59:05 media kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xf6, date = 2023-07-26

I tried again and got this error, is my cpu overheating?
